# Nodejs - Retry same function on error callback in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have a javascript function with setTimeOut and I am retrying to call same function, if any error from API call.I am calling same function in catch block.Is my node server is going crash and resources will be blocked or it will keep calling getData() function

```
 let retry = ()=> {
          setTimeout(() => {
           getData() 
           retry()
       }, 3000); 
   }

   let getData = () =>{
    Someapi.getData().then((token) => {
        console.log(`Data after 3 seconds->${token}`)
    }).catch((err) => {
        getData()

    })
   }
```

Comment: Why you calling again getData function if it failed previous time ? Also your script will call again it in 3 sec, you should probably 1) handle better error in catch block 2) end this loop at some point

Comment: @Ycotov , I am calling this getData function because it’s a third party api which gives me token which I set in process.env global variable to acces that token at app level so that it can be available to all users,refresh time to get new token is 60 second in production.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this work.

```
 let retry = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    getData();
    retry();
  }, 3000);
};

while (true) {
  let getData = () => {
    Someapi.getData()
      .then(token => {
        console.log(`Data after 3 seconds->${token}`);
        return false;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return true;
      });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this retry code in my project, it works well in production:

```js
const pause = (duration) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
};
const retry = (retryTimes, func, delay) => {
  return func().catch(
    (err) => {
      if(retryTimes > 0) {
        return pause(delay).then(
          () => retry(retryTimes - 1, func, delay * 2)
        );
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: where should I put my getData() function in you retry function.Please help me.

Comment: like this `retry(3, () => getData(), 500)`